# CakePHP 2 Auth does nothing when trying to log in

Tags: authentication, cakephp-2.1

I'am using cakePHP 2 and I have a weird issue with one of my customer when she tries to log in to the application. So here's the story: She has an account set in the DB, I am able to log in using her account information but she can't. She has no error displayed (like wrong email/password). 
When she press login, she hits the login form again.

So, in my AppController.php

```
public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
                'authorize' => array('Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')),
                'authenticate' => array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'email')))
    ),
    'RequestHandler',
    'Session'
);

public function beforeFilter() {
    $group = $this->Auth->user('Group.name');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');

    if ($group == 'customer') {
        $this->layout = "customer";
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'overviews', 'action' => 'index');
    }
    else {
        $this->layout = "default";
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index');
    }
 }
```

In my Config/core.php

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults'          => 'cake',
    'checkAgent'        => false,
    'timeout'           => '120',
));


Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
```

I really don't know where the problem could be... I am not able to reproduce the issue on my own computer.

EDIT : UsersController.php login()

```
public function login() {
    $this->layout = 'login';
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'));

        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Vos identifiants sont incorrectes.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code of the login action in the `Users` controller. Maybe the problem is there. Very important question: **do all users have this issue or just this one?**

Comment: Only one user from a specific computer (mac). I update the post

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the manual redirect from the login action:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'));
```

You have already set the `loginRedirect` property of the Auth component.

Otherwise this is strange. Ask the user to clear all broswer cache - cookies + cache.
Also check if all `tmp` dirs on the server are writable by the WebServer user - this includes the system `tmp` directory.

Comment on this post so we could continue to try to resolve this. It points over to a client-side issue but you never know. :D

Comment: So I tried to remove the manual redirect, but when I try to login, nothing is done (I hit the login page again). I also ask the user to clear all broswer cache including cookies. But didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @kdelemme what is the user browser? This is really obscure

Comment: Could you ask her to try with another browser? Firefox for example, since both Chrome and Safari use WebKit. It could be a WebKit related issue, hmm. Still very strange. :D